# Is "eats with hunger" a synonym of "eats greedily"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, synonyms

Is "eats with hunger" a synonym of "eats greedily"?

**A:**

> He eats with hunger

**B:**

> He eats greedily

Comment: I don't think _synonym_ is a verb :) B is a fine sentence, but A sounds off. Someone who eats greedily does not have to be hungry. Maybe they just like the food very much.

Comment: @oerkelens So :) what is the verb of *synonym*. The rest of the comment is understood.

Comment: _Synonyms_ are words with the same meaning. Two sentences can also have the same meaning or they can have a similar meaning. There is no one-word verb meaning _to mean the same_ as far as I know :)

Comment: There is no verb meaning "to be a synonym".  X *is a synonym* of Y.

Answer (score 1):

Hunger and greed are two different motivations.  [Hunger](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hunger) is a need for food; [greed](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/greed) is a wish to constantly get more, and is traditionally stigmatised on moral grounds.

"To eat with hunger" is to eat because you are hungry.  "To eat greedily" is to eat because you are greedy.

Comment: That all said, a very hungry person could eat greedily, so the two are not completely unrelated.

Comment: +1. If **greed** is used with eating it's a figurative or exaggerated use, perhaps describing an eater who looks around, making sure that no one is going to take his or her food away or try to get some of it.

Comment: @J.R. So, Can `eats with hunger` make up for `eagerly eats`? :)